# How to test if scroll is fired in react component?

Tags: reactjs, enzyme, jestjs

I'm trying to write a test for testing whether the scroll event fires or not when given a `shouldScroll` prop, can somebody help me out here please? This is the code I'm trying to test:

```
export default class HelloWorld extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.shouldScroll) {
      window.addEventListener('scroll', this.test);
    }
  }

  test() {
    console.log('scrolled...');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        hello world
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Test:

```
it('should fire onScroll event', () => {
  // how do I test above???
});
```

Comment: How would you calculate `shouldScroll`? This is interesting because scrolling is a GUI concept, not something that is easily translated to programmatic testing.

Comment: Might be related – https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45376974/what-is-the-best-way-to-test-window-scroll-event-handlers-with-enzyme

Answer (score 0):

You have to give `test(event)` for it to work. Also, you need to have a page that is long enough to have a scrollbar so that scroll event will be triggered.

You can add `hello world</br>` multiple times so that page will be long enough to have scrollbar.

```
  test(event) {
   console.log('scrolled...');
  }
```

Comment: Why does it need an event param inside test?  And why do I need to fill the page ? I'm trying to test it programatically using Jest / Enzyme